# How to limit the hours between 0 to 12, please?

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say it's 4 p.m, In my console, I display 16 hours (PM) instead of 4 hours (PM).

[image]

How to limit the hours between 0 to 12, please?

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  today: Date = new Date();
  
  hours: number = 0;
  minutes: number = 0;
  seconds: number = 0;

  flag: boolean = false; 
  day_night: string = "";

 
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.hours = 16;     //this.today.getHours();
    this.minutes = 40;   //this.today.getMinutes();
    this.seconds = 20;   //this.today.getSeconds();

    if (this.flag) {
      this.hours >= 12;
      this.day_night = "AM";     
    } else {
      this.day_night = "PM";    
    }

    console.log("It's " + this.hours + " hours, " + this.minutes + " minutes and " + this.seconds + " seconds.");
    console.log("Time of day => " + this.day_night);
    
  }

}
```

Comment: `this.hours % 12`

Comment: That is exactly and Only what you need todo `this.hours % 12`
as @Konrad Linkowski said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really simple.

After 12 it should circle back from 1 and then so on

You can use that by using [modulus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

You can achieve this by modifying the `if` statement like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.hours = 16;     //this.today.getHours();
    this.minutes = 40;   //this.today.getMinutes();
    this.seconds = 20;   //this.today.getSeconds();

    // If hours is greater then 12, it is PM, else it is AM
    if (this.hours > 12) {
      this.hours = this.hours % 12; // This will limit the value of hours under 12
      this.day_night = "PM";     
    } else {
      this.day_night = "AM";    
    }

    console.log("It's " + this.hours + " hours, " + this.minutes + " minutes and " + this.seconds + " seconds.");
    console.log("Time of day => " + this.day_night);
    
  }
```